# Collecting items with Kotlin streams

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

I have a `Player` that has `Bag`s, and each `Bag` has items (`String`):

```
class Player(val bags: List<Bag>)
class Bag(val items: List<String>)
```

I want to collect each bag and each item of it in a single list. Using nested for loops, I do it this way:

```
val player = Player(listOf(Bag(listOf("item1.1", "item1.2")), Bag(listOf("item2.1", "item2.2"))))
val list = mutableListOf<Any>()
for (bag in player.bags) {
    list.add(bag)
    for (item in bag.items) {
        list.add(item)
    }
}

//list contains [Bag@7adf9f5f, item1.1, item1.2, Bag@85ede7b, item2.1, item2.2]
```

How can I achieve the same behaviour using streams? I have tried this, but I just get the items, not the bags:

```
val list = player.bags.flatMap { bag -> bag.items }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, why do you want a `List<Any>`? You lose all type information by using this data type. You can't do anything with the elements in such a list, without doing some casting (except calling the methods on `Any`, of course).

If you really want to do it, you can use `flatMap` like this:

```
val list = player.bags.flatMap { bag -> listOf(bag) + bag.items }
```

If the order of the list is not important, I would just do this:

```
val list = player.bags.flatMap { it.items } + player.bags
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm totally agree with you. Actually, I'm not using a List<Any> but I simplified it for the question. + 1 for that point.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Kirill. I started writing the answer thinking it was a Scala question :P